# Leyenda de C3.js

Tags: javascript, c3.js

Me gustaría saber si cabe la posibilidad de darle eventos a una leyenda creada por mi mismo para que dichos eventos actúen en la gráfica, de la misma forma que actúa la leyenda de C3 de la gráfica.

Actualmente el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
$('#datos_grafica_windSpeed .datos_grafica_combo').on('mouseover',function(){
    if($(this).children('span').children('strong').html()!='0'){
        //chart_windSpeed.revert();
        chart_windSpeed.focus($(this).attr('id'));
        $(this).css('color','#444');
        $(this).css('text-shadow','#bbb 1px 1px');
    }
});
$('#datos_grafica_windSpeed .datos_grafica_combo').on('mouseout',function(){
    chart_windSpeed.revert();
    $(this).css('color','#5e5e5e');
    $(this).css('text-shadow','none');
});

$('#datos_grafica_windSpeed .datos_grafica_combo').on('click', function (id) {
    chart_windSpeed.toggle($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Funciona la funcionalidad de ocultar la linea de la gráfica cuando pulsas en la leyenda, pero el evento de cuando pones el ratón encima y se resalta la linea no funciona.

Añado también el JSP.

```
<div class="contenido_grafica_forecast">    
  <span class="cont_datos_grafica_forecast" id="datos_grafica_windSpeed">
  <span id="ws_forecast1_graf1" class="datos_grafica_combo">
  <span class="datos_cian"></span>
  <spring:message code="text.forecast"/>1</span>
  <span id="ws_forecast2_graf1" class="datos_grafica_combo">
     <span class="datos_oliva">
  </span>
  <spring:message code="text.forecast"/>2</span>
  <span id="ws_forecast3_graf1" class="datos_grafica_combo">
  <span class="datos_amarillo"></span>
  <spring:message code="text.forecast"/>3   </span>
 </span>                                    
</div>
```

Comment: Lo siento pero es el primer post que pongo, y olvide poner el código xD

Comment: Dices que el evento de hover no funciona. Te da errores en consola? Explicalo en la pregunta (no en los comentarios )

Comment: Haber, ya he conseguido que funcione, la cuestión es que no se nota casi nada cuando oculta las otras linea, la opacidad es mínima, entonces no se nota que esta resaltada. No da errores de consola.

Comment: ¿Hay opción de ver los datos con los que se genera la gráfica para intentar reproducirla?

Comment: La verdad es que no, son datos que recibimos desde una base de datos externa, y no puedo sacarlos. Lo siento y gracias.